# Decidability of validity of a sentence with only one quantifier

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

So, I realised that the validity and related notions of a quantifier-free first-order sentence is decidable.

I know that the validity of first-order sentences is not in general decidable. So, I am curious about "how many quantifiers it takes" for it to stop being decidable.

I am under the impression that the validity of a sentence with only one quantifier is decidable. For example, consider the sentence below, which we'll call $\sigma$,

$(\forall x (Px \leftrightarrow \neg Px) \to Qa) \lor Rb$

($a$ and $b$ are to denote closed terms)

We turn $\sigma$ into a zeroth-order sentence by substituting the prime formulas by atoms, and obtain $(A \to B) \lor C$. Now, the resulting sentence is not valid, but if it were, we'd know that $\sigma$ was valid.
So next we do the same, but for the subsentence in the range of the quantifier, i.e. $Px \leftrightarrow \neg Px$. The resulting zeroth-order sentence is unsatisfiable, so now we know that under any interpretation, $\sigma$ will always have a false implicant, thus always making the implication true, and consequently the disjunction as well.

Now, this is a bit messy, but I hope you get the idea.

So, is it correct to assume that the validity of a sentence with only one quantifier is decidable? I couldn't come up with any counterexamples.

Next, this method at first sight looks like it can just be iterated multiple times for sentences with multiple quantifiers, though I know that at some point validity won't be decidable anymore. When does that happen?

Comment: It is not a question of number of quantifiers but of "arity" of predicate letters. [Monadic predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_predicate_calculus) is decidable; adding a single binary relation symbol to monadic logic, however, results in an undecidable logic.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know where I can read more about this? Wiki doesn't expand any further on this last assertion unfortunately.

Comment: George Boolos & John Burgess & Richard Jeffrey, [Computability and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=nnAhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA295) (5th ed - 2007), **Ch.24 Decidability of Arithmetic without Multiplication**

Comment: Nice, I have this book! Haven't got to the later chapters though. Thanks.